# Pass a google authentication token to a WebView Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a website for an email service that allows users to login via google but that is not allowed inside of a WebView.

I tried to workaround that with changing useragents, but that did not help.

So I figured that I would need to have a second activity for signing in that passes the session to my WebView. How exactly would I go about that and does it even make sense?